# create table if no exists in opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

i get problem when using create table if not exists in open cart and here's my code

```
class ModelAccountOpentickets extends Model {
public function sendMessage($data) {

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "rbm_message SET customer_id = '" . (int)$data['customer_id'] . "', message = '" . $this->db->escape($data['message']) . "', sender = 'customer', date_added=NOW()");
}

public function getMessagesByCustomerId($data) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "rbm_message WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$data['customer_id'] . "' ORDER BY date_added DESC");

    return $query->rows;
}   

public function CreateTable(){
    $this->db->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "rbm_message` (`message_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`sender` varchar(20) NOT NULL,`message` text NOT NULL,`read_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,`date_added` datetime NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;");
}
}
```

here's the result

> **Notice**: Error: Table 'databas_rbm_message' doesn't exist
> Error No: 1146
> INSERT INTO databas_message SET customer_id = '2', message = 'ahmed khairy', sender = 'customer', date_added=NOW() in **/mysqli.php** on line **41**{"success":"text_success"}
>   what am doing wrong thank u

Comment: It appears you're trying to insert into the table before it exists. It would help to show the code you're using which calls these functions.

Comment: Okay, so it will create the table if it does not exist. When are you running `CreateTable()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to put the CreateTable code into the construct for the class:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->db->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS .......
}
```

This way, it always checks to see if the table exists (and creates it if it doesn't) when you open a new instance of the class, before it runs any other methods/functions.